Pyright cause reportAttributeAccessIssue on attrs validator

Environment
Python v3.9.13
Pyright 1.1.357
attrs 23.1.0

The code at official document of attrs library make the pyright type checker casue reportAttributeAccessIssue

https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/init.html#validators


Code

from attrs import define, field


@define
class C:
    x: int = field()

    @x.validator
    def _check_x(self, attribute, value):
        if value > 42:
            raise ValueError("x must be smaller or equal to 42")


Result of pyright

qwer.py:8:8 - error: Cannot access member "validator" for type "int"
    Member "validator" is unknown (reportAttributeAccessIssue)
1 error, 0 warnings, 0 informations

Instead of ignoring the issue, is there any way to resolve it?

Hello usan, while people are searching for an issue I'd like to wonder why you didn't consider to use pydantic for class validation? It is one the most convenient libraries for validation.

Also I would consider removing the decorator @x.validator and replacing it with
x: int =  field(validator=[self. _check_x])

FTR, I asked a similar question, but for PyCharm. It never got an answer.

@JohnnyCheesecutter I just prefer to minimize the use of external libraries, which is why I don't use pydantic

Pyright's support for attrs is, unfortunately, wildly inadequate. They took a hard stance on only supporting anything that gets standardized via PEPs for the new-ish "dataclass transform" API.
